# Rename commit/changeset in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit incorrect commit message in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623052/how-to-edit-incorrect-commit-message-in-mercurial)

Can i rename commit in mercurial before pushing on server from local repository?

I accidentally make commit with wrong name..(

Comment: How do you mean the wrong name? Do you mean the comment you put in when you did the commit?

Comment: yes wrong comment. i want fix it

Comment: Please read more answers than just the accepted answer in the other question. If you're using Mercurial Queues, you will probably prefer the second answer, instead of using `rollback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623052/how-to-edit-incorrect-commit-message-in-mercurial). Check that link, an answer is given there.

Importantly if you follow the advice on that page, **make sure you backup your latest changeset**. Performing a rollback will remove the latest changeset completely.

In fact, it may be wise to make a new clone of your working repository as a backup... just in case.