# How to edit Mercurial commit message after branching?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, commit-message

I have some old commit messages in a Mercurial repository that should be changed (to adjust for some new tools). I already understand that this hacking has to be done on the master repository and all local repositories would have to be re-cloned, because checksums of all subsequent changesets will also change.

I've tried following the recipes in "[How to edit incorrect commit messages in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623052/how-to-edit-incorrect-commit-message-in-mercurial)", but with MQ extension I got stuck on error message

```
X:\project>hg qimport -r 2:tip
abort: revision 2 is the root of more than one branch
```

and with Histedit quite similarly

```
X:\project>hg histedit 2
abort: cannot edit history that would orphan nodes
```

The problem seems to be that there have been branches created after the changeset.

I can see how it would become messy if I'd want to change the contents of patch, but perhaps there's a workaround that I've missed for editing the commit message?

Comment: Are you *really* sure you need to do this?  I'm pretty curious what sort of tooling change is forcing you to undertake this.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use MQ or HistEdit to edit a commit message after branching and I'm not aware of an other tool able to do that. @Sergey if you read the question carefully you will see that the link you provided is of no help at all, the OP already tried the solution proposed their ;)

Comment: @krtek I do read it carefully. particularly error message. so if repository already cloned between users it is problem for all users.

Comment: @JohnZwinck task management for a couple of projects was migrated to a new system, which picks up relationships with commits by the commit message. Currently, the messages have references only to old system, meaningless for the new one.

Comment: Sounds like it is time to write some compatibility logic into the new system.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a hacked version of the [convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) to do this. The extension can do **hg → hg** conversions which lets you alter author and branch names. There is not support for changing commit messages yet, but you can hack it.

Specifically, you should change the [getcommit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/hgext/convert/hg.py#l332) method from:

```
def getcommit(self, rev):
    ctx = self.changectx(rev)
    parents = [p.hex() for p in self.parents(ctx)]
    if self.saverev:
        crev = rev
    else:
        crev = None
    return commit(author=ctx.user(), date=util.datestr(ctx.date()),
                  desc=ctx.description(), rev=crev, parents=parents,
                  branch=ctx.branch(), extra=ctx.extra(),
                  sortkey=ctx.rev())
```

which is responsible for reading the old commits. Change the

```
desc=ctx.description()
```

to

```
desc=adjust(ctx.description())
```

and then implement the `adjust` function at the top of the file:

```
def adjust(text):
    return text.upper()
```

Answer (score 2):

If these are accidental/duplicate branches due to using `--amend` and `push --force` then strip them first and try 'histedit' again then wipe the central repo on bitbucket; try the following which worked for me:

Inspect the repository log and look for branches, you can use the [GraphlogExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GraphlogExtension) which you will have to enable first:

```
# hg log -G | more
...
o  changeset:   43:c2fcca731aa5
|  parent:      41:59669b9dfa4a
|  user:        Daniel Sokolowski (https://webdesign.danols.com)
|  date:        Tue Aug 27 20:14:38 2013 -0400
|  summary:     Progress snapshot: major content text and model instance  ..
...
| o  changeset:   42:c50724a6f1c6 
|/   user:        Daniel Sokolowski (https://webdesign.danols.com)
|    date:        Tue Aug 27 20:14:38 2013 -0400
|    summary:     Progress snapshot: major content text and model instance ...
|
o  changeset:   41:59669b9dfa4a
|  user:        Daniel Sokolowski (https://webdesign.danols.com)
...
```

Enable the [MqExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension) and strip all branches.

```
# hg strip --no-backup 42:c50724a6f1c6
# hg strip --no-backup 45:3420dja12jsa
...
```

If needed change the commit to 'draft' (see [Phases](http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/88203)) and re-run 'histedit' and all should be good now.

```
# hg histedit 14:599dfa4a669b
abort: cannot edit immutable changeset: b7cfa2f28bde
# hg phase -f -d 14:599dfa4a669b
# hg hsitedit 14:599dfa4a669ba
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar so I filed a [feature request](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4021).